# power of chi squared test for two proportions with gsDesign package in r

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, statistical-power, observational-study

I have problem with calculating power for two sided chi squared test for the following design:
Study includes 200 patients (100 patients per group). The null hypothesis is that 
p1=p2=30%  and alternative is p1=45% and p2=30%, where p1, p2 are proportions of patients having some feature in respectively group one and two.

In r package I use function nBinomial:
`nBinomial(p1=0.45,p2=0.3,alpha=0.05,n=200,outtype=2,sided=2)`
and the result is:
`0.5924098`.

On the other hand I've tried package pwr and function 
`pwr.chisq.test(w =0.2738613, N =200 , df = 1, sig.level =0.05)`
where w comes from formula on http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html.
The result is `power = 0.9721272`

Why these results are different ? Am I doing everything ok in nBinomial? because I'm obligated to use gsDesign package. Anyone have some sort of experience in gsDesign?